# Why do we use HTTP?

Tags: http

I understand the use of HTTP and how it works but i couldn't find a simple and precise answer that why we use HTTP to access any website?

PS: I am aware about it power .i.e. client server model, connection-less, stateless, SSL/TLS etc but that doesn't justify me why to use it.

Comment: As opposed to what alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is like asking: *"Why do I have to use 4 wheels to drive my car?"* (there are cars with fewer than 4 wheels but we assume one with 4 wheels to demonstrate the argument)

The answer is: *because there's no other way.*

First of all, you don't directly use the wheels, your car does. Similarly, you don't directly use HTTP (ie. you don't "talk HTTP"), your browser does. Also the server that serves the website does.

> PS: I am aware about it power .i.e. client server model, connection-less, stateless, SSL/TLS etc but that doesn't justify me why to use it.

Because you can't do otherwise. HTTP is a *communications* protocol implemented for "accessing and viewing websites". So the only way to "view a website" is by talking the HTTP protocol.

What happens is you type the URL in the browser, the browser talks the HTTP protocol to communicate with the server and get the page back to you.

Comment: There _are_ cars with fewer or more than 4 wheels ;)

Comment: Incorrect. A server and client can communicate using whatever protocol their developers created. There's no obligation to use http. Also, one could use a custom protocol that is stateless, uses tcp/ip, etc, without being http. For example, one that is similar to http but puts the url behind the method instead of in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is: why shouldn't we use it?

You need a way to communicate with the server that is holding your content. So there needs to be a way to request the data and let it deliver the data. This is accomplished by HTTP.

The other options are Gopher ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol) ), HTTPS or HTTP2
The last two depend on HTTP and add a encryption layer (simplyfied).

Gopher is similar to the HTTP approach but limited in its multimedia support - it has other advantages. Take a look at the linked wikipedia article if you want to know more.